# Need help to setup/shape a new project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

we are creating a new react project using `create-react-apps` and we are trying to figure out a way to organise our page components. After some discussion, we basically have come up with 2 solutions

#### the first solution is to use hierarchical structure as shown below

```
src/
├── copmonents/
│   ├── sharedComponent1
│   ├── sharedComponent2
│   ├── sharedComponent3
|   └── sharedComponent4
├── pages/
│   ├── page1/
│   |     ├── component1/
│   |     |        ├── component11/
│   |     |        |       ├── component111
│   |     |        |       └── component112
│   |     |        └── component12
│   |     └── component12
│   ├── page2 (same as above)
│   └── page3 (same as above)
└── utils/
```

We create pages and put components inside them. Once we find a component is used in multiple places, we hoist it into the `component` folder.

Idea behind is to use file hierarchy to reflect component structure. We fell developers might find it easier to locate files using this solution, but drawback would be it can easily go too deep?

#### the second solution is to use a 'flat' structure

```
src/
├── copmonents/
│   ├── component1
│   ├── component2
│   ├── component3
│   ├── component4
│   ├── component5
│   ├── component6
│   ├── component7
│   ├── component8
│   ├── component9
|   └── component10
├── pages/
│   ├── page1.tsx
│   ├── page2.tsx
|   └── page3.tsx
└── utils/
```

this way we have a very lean page folder and keep all components into a `components` folder. While this structure seems to be cleaner than the first one, I do agree that some people may feel this solution "less organised" as all components are dumped into a centralised place.

I do recognise this is a highly opinionated topic and I was thinking of using `json normaliser` as an analogy, but people even have different opinions in normalizing json.

thoughts?

Comment: *opinion*, though regarding the first structure: suppose `component112` suddenly is required in `page3`. Think of the amount of code changes. The component needs to move, at least `page1` needs to change (maybe sub components too), and only then can you start using it in `page3`...

Comment: I do prefer something more like the second option. Complementing your thoughts, if you realize that your components folder became too "unorganized" you could try to create sub-folders inside it

Answer (score 0):

**Move files around until it feels right** [ref](https://dev.to/dance2die/move-files-around-until-it-feels-right-2lek)

[Dan Abramov’s site](http://react-file-structure.surge.sh/)

But, you can aboard it strategically with features (layout, Button, basket)

```
src/
├── copmonents/
│   ├── Layout
│   ├── Basket
│   ├── Button
|   └── Feature specific
├── pages/
│   ├── page1/
│   |     ├── index.ts/js/
│   |     ├── logic.tsx
│   |     └── ui-specific-to-page
│   ├── page2 (same as above)
│ 
└ hooks
```

Answer (score 0):

one point that I missed in my initial post(I only discovered it yesterday),  with the hierarchical code structure, we will end up with long referrence paths like `../../../../utils` inside your components (imagine you are referring to a utils function inside `component111` or it's sub components). While with the flat structure we don't have this type of issues.

there are ways to get around with it, like a custom `resolve` for `webpack`, but it may involve some effort to set it up (especially when your project is bootstrapped by `cra`)

```
src/
├── copmonents/
│   ├── sharedComponent1
│   ├── sharedComponent2
│   ├── sharedComponent3
|   └── sharedComponent4
├── pages/
│   ├── page1/
│   |     ├── component1/
│   |     |        ├── component11/
│   |     |        |       ├── component111
│   |     |        |       └── component112
│   |     |        └── component12
│   |     └── component12
│   ├── page2 (same as above)
│   └── page3 (same as above)
└── utils/
```